# AngularJs DOM manipulation inside Directive without Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Let's start right away, Let's say this is my directive:

```
appDirectives.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'directives/template.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
              // maybe by element or attr access to the dom inside the template
        }
    };
});
```

And this is my template:

```
 <div class='col-md-12 videoholder' id="sliderContainer">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <div class="myLangaugesholder"></div>
</div>
```

Normally I would use (but that's bad practice in Angular)

```
document.getElementById('myCanvas').style.opacity = 0.6;
```

**my Question**

How do I access the ID (for example myCanvas) inside a directive **without Jquery**. I tried it with the element parameter but then I only get access to the `<div data-myDirective></div>`. **Best Practices, Code examples** are always welcome!

Comment: use ` <canvas id="myCanvas" my-directive></canvas>`

Comment: Check out what [jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) offers.  I would do: `element.find('canvas')`.

Comment: PS don't use an id in your template unless you're setting the value inside your directive.  Otherwise you're limiting the directive to only being able to be used once on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty native DOM methods. In your case you can just use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)/querySelectorAll:

```
appDirectives.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'directives/template.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var canvas = element[0].querySelector('canvas');
            canvas.style.opacity = 0.6;
        }
    };
});
```

Also make sure you don't use ids inside your directive template, since directive is supposed to be reusable. This directive template is much better:

```
<div class='col-md-12 videoholder' class="slider-container">
    <canvas class="my-canvas"></canvas>
    <div class="my-langauges-holder"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JqueryKing `templateUrl: 'directives/template.html'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#myCanvas'));
```

Answer (score -1):

In directive

```
appDirectives.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'directives/template.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
             $(element).css('opacity', '0.6');
        }
    };
});
```

in html

```
<div class='col-md-12 videoholder' id="sliderContainer">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" my-directive></canvas>
    <div class="myLangaugesholder"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP said without jQuery.